# Sectigo SSL certificate - SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: certificates, ssl

I'm trying to send a HTTP request to a service hosted on the domain salesforceearth.com, however it's returning the above error. The SSL certificate recently expired so I replaced it and this error has occurred ever since. The rest of the cert chain is exactly the same as the last certificate's, which was working fine until now. I've noticed that the root certificate for the site is not on the list of outbound messaging SSL Certificates (https://cs32.salesforce.com/cacerts.jsp), would this be the issue or is there something else I need to check? The cert chain is below if that helps:
[image: cert chain]

Thanks, alex